# Grails async integration testing

Tags: grails

I've a Grails 2.5.6 project with a rest controller in which I create n async tasks each of them invoking a method in a service like this:

```
// MyController
...
def statuses = ['where', 'ownership', 'store']
def tasks = statuses.collect { st ->
    task {
        return myService.invokeMethod(st, [aDomain, data])
    }
}
def props = waitAll(tasks)
...


// MyService
...
store(aDomain, data) {
    ...
    def store = Store.get(data.store)
    ...
}
```

If I execute the application, the Store is correctly found in the database.

I've also created an integration test. To avoid conflicts with existing data in the database I create a new `Store` during the test:

```
// Integration test (simplified)
....
def store = new Store(....)
store.save(flush: true)
...
def json = [store: store.id] as JSON
...
controller.request.content = params.toString()
controller.request.method = "POST"
controller.update()
...
```

If I execute the tests, the new store created is not found in the service and the test fails.
I've verified the situation in some points of the application and found that:
- if I search the store in the controller (before or after the tasks are executed), it is found
- if I list all the stores in the service method the new store doesn't exist.

I suppose that this behaviour is due to how hibernate session is handled during tests but I don't know how to solve it.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Synchronouse promise factory for tests.

```
void setup() { 
  Promises.promiseFactory = new SynchronousPromiseFactory()
}
```